# The same name distinction in Civicrm

Tags: civicontribute, civicontact

i doing customize CiviCRM 5.29.1 for Wordpress 5.5.1 last version.

i have many student the same lastname,midlename,lastname

Ex:

Student 1:Nguyen Hoang Phuong, ID:123456

Student 2:Nguyen Hoang Phuong, ID:123457

Student 3:Nguyen Hoang Phuong, ID:123458

All my student only have ID, not email address. only ID difference

ID is my custom field. can i change email to ID when select student in soft credit?
easy for select right student.

see attached
[image]

Thanks

Comment: why use a Custom Field - why not use External ID since that is exactly what it is designed for?

Answer (score 1):

If you combine Demerit's and Pete's suggestions.

1. Update Sort Name Format to include the External Identifer token
   {contact.external_identifier}
2. Export your current id field entries and re-inport them into the standard External Identifier Field

You can then search by external id in the soft credt option

[image: screenshot of soft credit- with external id showing]

Comment: Dammit. just seen original post is over a year old.

Only answered because it was showing in the "active" questions last.

Ah well, I guess it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Under Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Display Preferences, near the bottom, there's a setting for "Individual Sort Name Format". You can add in some tokens here. Not all tokens work so I don't know if there's one for your custom id, but if there isn't you might be able to find another useful field.

[image]

Note when you click save it won't automatically update existing contacts. You'd need to edit and re-save those.

Comment: Thanks, default field then working well, but not working with custom field. huhu.

difficult for select many contact same name. huhu, can you help me another idea. thank so much